# Print Google Spreadsheet cells to PDF file

Tags: javascript, pdf, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I want to print cells from a sheet to a PDF file. This PDF file should not be created in Google Drive but downloadable to disk.
Here is my code:

```
function PrintPDF(LigneDebut, ColonneDebut, LigneFin, ColonneFin) {
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  feuilleImprimer = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = feuilleImprimer.getActiveSheet();

  var gid = sheet.getSheetId();

  var pdfOpts = '&size=A4&fzr=false&portrait=true&fitw=true&gridlines=false&printtitle=false&sheetnames=false&pagenum=UNDEFINED&attachment=false&gid='+gid;

  var printRange = '&c1='+ColonneDebut + '&r1='+LigneDebut + '&c2='+ColonneFin + '&r2='+LigneFin; // B2:APn
  var url = feuilleImprimer.getUrl().replace(/edit$/, '') + 'export?format=pdf' + pdfOpts + printRange;

  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setWidth(200).setHeight(150);
  app.setTitle('Printing ' + feuilleImprimer.getSheetName());

  var link = app.createAnchor('Download PDF', url).setTarget('_new');
  app.add(link);

  feuilleImprimer.show(app);
}
```

Some APIs are out of date: *UiApp*, *Anchor*, and *UiInstance*.
This generates warning messages.
By what methods to replace these deprecated API?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

To address the deprecated issue, just go to the official Apps Script doc reference. For example, in the case Class UiApp, use the [HTML Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/) instead.

For a working code of converting spreadsheet to pdf and download, check [ixhd/gist:3660885](https://gist.github.com/ixhd/3660885) and [Convert and Email Google Spreadsheets as PDF Files](https://ctrlq.org/code/19869-email-google-spreadsheets-pdf).

Comment: Great! Thank you.
All examples create a PDF file in Google Drive. Is it possible to create the PDF file in a folder on the hard drive? Or a link to download the file as in the UiApp method?